# Creating a dll using libcurl in c++ with MinGW

Tags: c++

```
**How to make a dll using libcurl. can you share me a sample code.**



#include <math.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h> 
   #include <string.h> 
   #include <iostream>

   #include <curl/curl.h>

   using namespace std; string data; typedef
   #ifdef BUILDING_TESTCURL_DLL
   #define TESTCURL_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
   #else
   #define TESTCURL_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
   #endif


                curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL); //pretty obvious
                curl = curl_easy_init();

                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, lpURL);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeCallback);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
                curl_easy_perform(curl);

                if (data == "1")
                {
                    //printf("Successfull");
                    strcpy(Result, "1");


                }

                v5 = 1;
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
                curl_global_cleanup();

    size_t TESTCURL_DLL writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t
   nmemb, void* up) { 

    for (int c = 0; c<size*nmemb; c++)  {       data.push_back(buf[c]);
        //printf("", buf[c]);   }   return size*nmemb; //tell curl how many
   bytes we handled }
```

I run this code with MinGW: g++ -shared -o testcurl.dll testcurl.o           -Wl,--out-implib,libcurldll.a

it shows error: undefined reference to '_imp_curl_easy_setopt' undefined reference to '_imp_curl_easy_perform' undefined reference to '_imp_curl_easy_init'

Please help me for developing a dll file using curl.

Comment: You are not linking against `libcurl`. Try adding `-llibcurl` to your compile command. If you installed curl correctly into your MinGW installation, it should be found.

Comment: its not working. Please see the link which is my working directory: [link] http://prntscr.com/578uv5

Comment: okay, maybe you have the dynamic version of libcurl (`-llibcurl.dll`). How have you installed curllib into MinGW? Is it located in your MSYS `/usr/lib`?

Comment: i am using windows 7. Before i am trying to develop dll with libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc.7z. but not successful. then i have downloaded curl-7.16.4.zip and i make the curl with mingw. then i am trying to develop a dll file. not yet successful. please see the screenshot which is my whole directory. Link: 1. http://prntscr.com/5796oy. 2. http://prntscr.com/5796wa. 3. http://prntscr.com/57972e

Comment: Ok, please try adding the following to your command line (case senstitive!): `-LC:/vd/curl/lib -llibcurl.dll`. If this works, then you haven't installed curl into MinGW. For the static version of curl omit the `.dll` extension in the command. If it fails, please post your whole command line you have used.